# anacondaのspyderでprintできない。DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, anaconda3, spyder

Error解消方法を教えてください。
プログラミング初心者です。

**目的**
spyderでprint"hello world!"を表示させる。

**前提条件**

- anaconda Ver.3.7.4
- spyder Ver.3.3.6

をインストールしています。

インストール時にPATHにチェック入れてインストールしました。
PCは、win10を使用しています。

**エディター**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jan 25 16:36:32 2020

@author: rika
"""

print("hello world")
```

**IPythonコンソール**

最後の2行の表示

```
raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")

DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

この前に28行ほどの表示があります。

Comment: 問題解決には「この前に28行ほどの表示があります。」の内容が知りたいです。anacondaからspyder を起動し、新しいファイルを新規作成し、print("hello world")を書いて、実行ボタン(緑の三角形のボタン)をクリックするとhello worldが表示されました。何か大きな誤解があると思いました。

Comment: 朝、実行して表示されたものがこれです。

runfile('C:/home/sample.pyx', wdir='C:/home')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-4bad32e2abdb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/home/sample.pyx', wdir='C:/home')

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 825, in runfile
    ipython_shell.run_cell_magic('cython', '', f.read())

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2359, in run_cell_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "<C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-131>", line 2, in cython

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py", line 333, in cython
    quiet=args.quiet)

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py", line 443, in _build_extension
    build_extension.run()

Comment: File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)

Comment: File "C:\Users\rika fujii\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 426, in compile
    raise CompileError(msg)

CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: anaconda等、アンインストールして、再インストールした関係でしょうか？

Comment: Lilica16820sさんは`Cython`で`print("hello world")`を実行しようとされているのでしょうか。そうであれば`Cython`を使っていることを質問に明記すると、回答が付きやすくなると思います。残念ながら私は`Cython`を使ったことがないためお役に立てそうにありません。spyderをどのように操作をしたのか、実行前に何をしたのかを質問に追記することも必要だと思います。「Windows 10＋Anaconda＋Python 3.7でCythonを使う」 'https://qiita.com/query1000/items/d4549d99fd87cf750b73' も参考になると思います。この記事を読むと、Cythonを使うときいろいろな設定や手順が必要のようです。Cythonで実行する必要がないならANACONDA　NAVIGATORからSpyderを起動し、Spyderでソースファイル(Sample.py)を作成し、実行するだけでよいと思います。

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。
お手数をおかけいたしました。
トライしてみます。

Comment: 単にspyder でprint("hello world")を実行したいだけなのなら、CythonやIPythonは関係なさそうです。anacondaの再インストールは関係あるかもしれません。アンインストールが不完全だったのかもしれません。anacondaとspyderを別々にインストールしたり、再インストールするとき別の場所にインストールしたりすると問題が発生するかもしれません。